# Infinite child nodes in TreeView using DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, datatemplate, children

Is there any way to create infinite children nodes in `TreeView` using **`DataTemplate`**?

I read lots of tutorials, but all of them show only manually populated `TreeView`. I need to populate my `TreeView` from database.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `HierarchicalDataTemplate`; To populate data from DB you will have to first fetch the data, create proper `DataModel` objects and then use them to populate the `TreeView`. I would also suggest you to use MVVM for this, MVVM makes it very easy to work with `TreeView`.

Have a look at following great article from Josh Smith explaining both these (and much more)-

[Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)